# Increasing spacing of dots in vdots

Tags: spacing, bordermatrix

Basically I want a `\vdotsfor` command that does what `\hdotsfor` does but for vertical dots. Need to increase spacing of dots over two rows so it looks pretty instead of having to use two `\vdots` on both rows. (The other thread that is top-related to this has some code but it doesn't do anything for me.)

Comment: "The other thread that is top-related..." Which other thread?

Comment: Sorry, this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/spacing-of-vdots-in-a0poster-class

Comment: Would this help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4746/same-height-for-list-of-comma-separated-vectors/4795#4795

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether this is what the OP wants: basically I put vertical dots inside a `\multirow` command, adapting the spread to the number of rows spanned. The spacing doesn't work, so I provide an extra argument to shift the thing vertically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\vdotrows}[2][-15pt]{%
  \multirow{#2}{*}{%
    \vbox {%
      \baselineskip = \dimexpr 2pt\relax 
      \multiply\baselineskip by #2\relax
      \advance\baselineskip by 2pt\relax
      \lineskiplimit = 0pt\relax
      \kern 6pt\relax
      \vskip #1\relax%
      \hbox {.}\hbox {.}\hbox {.}}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\[
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
  1            & 2            & \cdots & 2 & 2      \\
  \vdotrows[4pt]{3} & 1       &        &   & 2      \\
               & \vdotrows{2} & \ddots &   & \vdots \\
               &              &        & 1 & 2      \\
  1            & 1            & \cdots & 1 & 1      \\
\end{array}
\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

In its environments, the package `nicematrix` provides a command `\vdotsfor` similar to `\hdotsfor`. Customization of that dotted rules is possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\begin{pNiceArray}{ccccc}
  1            & 2            & \cdots & 2 & 2      \\
  \Vdotsfor{3} & 1            &        &   & 2      \\
               & \Vdotsfor{2} & \ddots &   & \vdots \\
               &              &        & 1 & 2      \\
  1            & 1            & \cdots & 1 & 1      \\
\end{pNiceArray} \\
\begin{pNiceArray}{ccccc}[xdots/shorten=3mm]
  1            & 2            & \cdots & 2 & 2      \\
  \Vdotsfor{3} & 1            &        &   & 2      \\
               & \Vdotsfor{2} & \ddots &   & \vdots \\
               &              &        & 1 & 2      \\
  1            & 1            & \cdots & 1 & 1      \\
\end{pNiceArray}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]