# Left/right scripts with horizontal centering

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I have been using

```
\newcommand{\lrscript}[3]{\raisebox{.5ex}{\llap{\scriptsize$#2$}}#1\raisebox{.5ex}{\rlap{\scriptsize$#3$}}}
```

to produce the middle segment of things like this:

[image: \begin{array}{c}[\Gamma]\\lrscript{\vdots}{\pi}{\exists\text{-free}}\\hline\phi\end{array}]

Produced with

```
\[
\begin{array}{c}
[\Gamma]\\
\lrscript{\vdots}{\pi}{\exists\text{-free}}\\
\hline
\phi
\end{array}
\]
```

which uses the `amsmath` package.

It works fine most of the time but I prefer to avoid manually raising boxes when I can, so I keep wondering if there is a smarter way to reach this kind of horizontal and vertical alignment. (Note that this command is often deeply nested in more complex constructs.)

Comment: Can you please show a use case of your macro?

Comment: @egreg: I added the code I used to generate the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exploit `\vcenter`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\lrscript}[3]{%
  \vcenter{\llap{$\scriptstyle\mathstrut#2$}}
  \vcenter{\hbox{$#1$}}
  \vcenter{\rlap{$\scriptstyle\mathstrut#3$}}
}
\makeatletter % Hendrik Vogt (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4827)
\def\vcdots{\vbox{\baselineskip4\p@ \lineskiplimit\z@
    \kern3\p@\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\kern3\p@}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\existsfree}{\exists\text{-free}}

\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{c}
[\Gamma] \\
\lrscript{\vcdots}{\pi}{\existsfree} \\
\hline
\phi
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

The macro `\vcdots` for better vertical dots is by [Hendrik Vogt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4827)

[image]

Comment: Neat! Is there a `\vbottom` too?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais It's `\vbox`.